# Use 4.1 style passwords MySQL .NET

Tags: mysql, authentication

I've been experiencing this problem for hours now and I've tried many 'solutions' but none worked. Can you guys please help?

I have tried this before on MySQL Workbench;

```
SET old_passwords=FALSE
SET PASSWORD=PASSWORD('your_new_password_here')
```

Those 2 lines do not work, I get the error "Unknown system variable old_passwords"

This is what I get, when I try to open my project:
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Authentication with old password no longer supported, use 4.1 style passwords.

Comment: [old_passwords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_old_passwords) was removed in 8.0.11. Maybe install the latest [net connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/). Recommend describing the problem and not just the failed solution. Include version number of software.

Comment: I am having the problem "Authentication with old password no longer supported, use 4.1 style passwords." and tried all the solutions there are on stackoverflow. I did download and setup newest .NET CONNECTOR, it didn't solve my problem. My MySQL Workbench version is 8.0.16 14498383 CE. 
It also throws "Bad Handshake" when I try to create new connection using 127.0.0.1; the problem goes away when I try localhost instead. 
What else should I be sharing?